# Android studio on linux: Gradle build is too slow. It lasts more than 1 hour

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I don't know why the Gradle build is so slow in Android Studio on linux (Debian Jessie).

It started 1 hour ago and it still running.

This is what I tried without haveing success:

- Check "Work offline" in Settings menu
- Check "Compile indipendent modules in parallel" in Settings menu
- Check "Configure on demand" in Settins menu
- Created a "gradle.properties" file in my home/.gradle folder with this line: org.gradle.daemon=true
- Changed "jcenter()" with "marvelCentral()" in build.gradle file

I didn't figure out yet what's wrong.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: What project are you compiling? On what computer? There is no 'marvelCentral'. Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: A little project on I7 core with 8gb of RAM. Yes, I tried both jcentral() and marvelCentral().

Comment: Hehe. "marvelCentral". This isn't the Avengers... It's Maven Central

Answer (score 0):

Try to specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process you enabled by adding this two lines to your `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Comment: I think he's aware of it. It has been discussed like million times

Comment: Tried those lines in the project file "gradle.properties", not in my home folder. No solution. It is running from 36 mins right now.